# decrease string in python doesn't works

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a problem to cut the url that i get as result from Beautifulsoup, i've used this code to retrieve the url.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://192.168.0.184:88/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi? cmd=snapPicture&usr=USER&pwd=PASS'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
imgs = soup.findAll("img")
print imgs
print imgs[1:]
```

As result from print imgs i get `[<img src="../snapPic/Snap_20160401-110642.jpg"/>]`
I want to cut the unwanted characters from this string so i try to use for eg. print imgs[1:] but as result i get []

Any tips or solutions?
I want to rebuild the imgs string to the correct image url
`imgs string = <img src="../snapPic/Snap_20160401-110642.jpg"/>`
wanted result = `http://192.168.0.184:88/snapPic/Snap_20160401-110642.jpg`

Comment: what do you get with print imgs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://192.168.0.184:88/cgi-bin/CGIProxy.fcgi? cmd=snapPicture&usr=USER&pwd=PASS'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
imgs = soup.findAll("img")
print imgs
for img in imgs:
   print img["src"].replace("..","http://192.168.0.184:88")
```

Comment: I get this as result

[<img src="../snapPic/Snap_20160401-114529.jpg"/>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foscam1.py", line 12, in <module>
    print img[1:]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
TypeError: unhashable type

Comment: I can only see partial stack trace.

Comment: From your response the error occurs in line five which is `html = urllib2.urlopen(url)`.